general form for effective magazine size with refunded bullets
This exploration started because of the video game destiny, in which weapons can have essentially magical perks, such as every 3rd shot hit, add one bullet back into the magazine.
What I am curious about is being able to answer the question, if I have n rounds, and a list of "refund cadences" like every 3 and every 4 and every 5, how many rounds can I actually shoot before running out.
In the simplest case, with one refund cadence c, I believe the formula is floor $\frac{cx-1}{c-1}$
now if we extend to consider 2 refund cadences [c1,c2].  I am already at a loss.  If they happen to be of a special case where the sum of the fractions $\frac{1}{c1}$ + $\frac{1}{c2}$ = $\frac{k-1}{k}$ such as for [2,3] and [2,4], then it can be formulated very simply as kn-k-1, but this only works for n where bullets(n,[c1]) >= c2
What I am hoping for is a non brute force method to calculate bullets(n,cadences) for a cadence list of any length.
for a further challenge one could consider cadences with different refund amounts, such as 1 every 3 and 2 every 4, which seems to exactly follow this formula someone else produced: 6(n-4) + 2(n mod 2) + 11, again with the hitch of only for n >= 3
some python code I wrote to experiment with creating the fastest algorithm to calculate, but it only works for 2 cadences.

def bullet_base(n,i):
    return int((i*n-1)/(i-1))

def bullet_simulate(n,bases):
    f=0
    while n>0:
       n-=1
       f+=1
       for base in bases:
          if f % base == 0:
             n+=1
    return f

def calc_bullets(n,bases,verbose = False):
   lazy = bullet_base(n,bases[0])
   if len(bases)==1:
      return lazy
   if lazy < bases[1]:
      return lazy
   mod = 1
   for base in bases:
      mod *= base
   mod -= sum(bases)
   if mod == 1:
      mod += sum(bases)
      return mod*n - (mod+1)
   mults = int(n/mod)
   if mults:
      if verbose:
        print("we cut out " + str(mults) + " corners")
      base = bullet_simulate(mod,bases)
      amount = bullet_simulate(mod*2,bases) - base
      amount *= mults-1
      amount += base
      n-=mults*mod
      return bullet_simulate(mod + n,bases) - base + amount
   return bullet_simulate(n,bases)


base = [2,5]

#print(calc_bullets(34,[3],True))
#print(bullet_simulate(34,[3]))

for i in range(1,1000):
   if calc_bullets(i,base) != bullet_simulate(i,base):
      print("sadge " + str(i))
      break

